# Ayuda con diseño bootstrap Sidebar accordion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un sitio web basado el siguiente [diseño](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/). Al abrir mi pagina se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que quiero que la barra vertical izquierda se comprima al abrir la pagina, es decir, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!-- Sidebar -->
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

 <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
<a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
 <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
 <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">SB Admin <sup>2</sup></div>
 </a>
 <!-- Divider -->
  <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

 <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
 <li class="nav-item active">
 <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
 <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
 <span>Dashboard</span></a>
 </li>

 <!-- Divider -->
 <hr class="sidebar-divider">

 <!-- Heading -->
 <div class="sidebar-heading">
    Interface
 </div>

 <!--BLA BLA BLA-->
 
 <!-- Divider -->
  <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

 <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
 <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
 <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle">  </button>
 </div>

 </ul>
 <!-- End of Sidebar -->
```

Comment: Pues agrega a la etiqueta body el `class="sidebar-toggled"` y en la etiqueta `<ul>` agrega la clase `toggled`. Saludos.

Comment: En realidad, solo con la clase `toggled` en la etiqueta `ul` es suficiente.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez Muchas gracias, que verguenza jaja, pero me podrian explicar porque funciono asi?, osea como dedujeron eso?

Comment: @JheymanMejia ?

Comment: @Huntzberger , mira logré saber como hacerlo por que uso inspeccionar elemento del navegador chrome, entonces me fuí hasta el elemento que contenía tu sidebar, lo que hice después fue accionar el botón y logré que cambios pasa en los elementos, si te fijas cambiará de clases.

Comment: Exactamente, es un script que está amarrado al botón el que genera esa acción. Puedes ver información relacionada aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

Comment: Animo a @SebastiánLagosYañez para que añada su respuesta por simple que parezca, esto con el fín de generar información de consulta para futuros visitantes.

Comment: Bueno lo dejaré como respuest, pero está más completa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno para tu caso simplemente tienes que trabajar con las clases, la forma de saber cómo es que actúan los elementos es inspeccionarlos con el inspeccionar del navegador que usas, que yo sepa firefox y chrome lo tienen, entonces vas a el elemento que contiene tu sidebar y accionas el botón y verás los cambios que tienen de clases, por eso es que para ti basta con poner el class `toggled` en la etiqueta `<ul>`

```html
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Page Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion toggled" id="accordionSidebar">

    <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
    <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
      <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
        <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">SB Admin <sup>2</sup></div>
    </a>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

    <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span></a>
    </li>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <hr class="sidebar-divider">

    <!-- Heading -->
    <div class="sidebar-heading">
      Interface
    </div>

    <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
        <span>Components</span>
      </a>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
          <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
        <span>Utilities</span>
      </a>
      <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
          <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Utilities:</h6>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-color.html">Colors</a>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-border.html">Borders</a>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-animation.html">Animations</a>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-other.html">Other</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <hr class="sidebar-divider">

    <!-- Heading -->
    <div class="sidebar-heading">
      Addons
    </div>

    <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsePages" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePages">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
        <span>Pages</span>
      </a>
      <div id="collapsePages" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingPages" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
        <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
          <h6 class="collapse-header">Login Screens:</h6>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Login</a>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="register.html">Register</a>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a>
          <div class="collapse-divider"></div>
          <h6 class="collapse-header">Other Pages:</h6>
          <a class="collapse-item" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
          <a class="collapse-item active" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Nav Item - Charts -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
        <span>Charts</span></a>
    </li>

    <!-- Nav Item - Tables -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
        <span>Tables</span></a>
    </li>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

    <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
    <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
      <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
    </div>

  </ul>
  <!-- End of Sidebar -->

  <!-- Content Wrapper -->
  <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div id="content">

      <!-- Topbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

        <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
        <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>

        <!-- Topbar Search -->
        <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                  <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

          <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
            </a>
            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
              <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                      </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>

          <!-- Nav Item - Alerts -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="alertsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i>
              <!-- Counter - Alerts -->
              <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Dropdown - Alerts -->
            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                Alerts Center
              </h6>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="mr-3">
                  <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</div>
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">A new monthly report is ready to download!</span>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="mr-3">
                  <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
                    <i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</div>
                  $290.29 has been deposited into your account!
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="mr-3">
                  <div class="icon-circle bg-warning">
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</div>
                  Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <!-- Nav Item - Messages -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="messagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
              <!-- Counter - Messages -->
              <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                Message Center
              </h6>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                  <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/fn_BT9fwg_E/60x60" alt="">
                  <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="font-weight-bold">
                  <div class="text-truncate">Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a problem I've been having.</div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">Emily Fowler · 58m</div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                  <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/AU4VPcFN4LE/60x60" alt="">
                  <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="text-truncate">I have the photos that you ordered last month, how would you like them sent to you?</div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">Jae Chun · 1d</div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                  <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/CS2uCrpNzJY/60x60" alt="">
                  <div class="status-indicator bg-warning"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="text-truncate">Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with the progress so far, keep up the good work!</div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">Morgan Alvarez · 2d</div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                  <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Mv9hjnEUHR4/60x60" alt="">
                  <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="text-truncate">Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...</div>
                  <div class="small text-gray-500">Chicken the Dog · 2w</div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Read More Messages</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

          <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Valerie Luna</span>
              <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QAB-WJcbgJk/60x60">
            </a>
            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i> Profile
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i> Settings
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i> Activity Log
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i> Logout
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </nav>
      <!-- End of Topbar -->

      <!-- Begin Page Content -->
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Blank Page</h1>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Main Content -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
      <div class="container my-auto">
        <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
          <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- End of Footer -->

  </div>
  <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

<!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
<a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
  <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>

<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
```

Pon este snippet en pantalla completa para lo veas . Espero te ayude .Saludos.